# AWS Codebuild: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Expected Variables to be of map type:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am getting the YAML error in `buildspec.yaml` file. The error is:

```
[Container] 2021/11/09 06:18:34 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2021/11/09 06:18:35 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/11/09 06:18:40 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/11/09 06:18:40 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src909937249/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/nftytest
[Container] 2021/11/09 06:18:40 YAML location is /codebuild/readonly/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2021/11/09 06:18:42 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/11/09 06:18:42 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Expected Variables to be of map type: found string instead at line 5, check indentation or content around the line num
```

My Buildspec looks like the following

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST:"1"
phases:
  install:
    commands:
       - yum install python3 -y
       - python3 -m venv venv
       - source venv/bin/activate
       - curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
       - pip3 install -r requirements/local.txt
```

It gives on `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST:"1"` line.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how to solve the issue?

Comment: @Marcin sorry I did not visit it and it did not let me accept answers within minutes at that time. Your solution worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a **space**:

```
env:
  variables:
    CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST: "1"
```